# Merge a list of SpatialLines

Tags: r, sp

I started off with a SpatialPointsDataFrame, containing locations from animals wearing GPS loggers. Aside from the coordinates, the data frame also contains the animals' ID and a timestamp.

From this SpatialPointsDataFrame, I created lines that show the trajectory of each animal over the tracking period. I've used the following code:

`spdf4tri`#the SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
ids=unique(spdf4tri$id)
trajectory <- list()
 for (i in ids){ 
   spdf4bird<-subset(spdf4tri, id==i)
   birdtrajectory<-SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(spdf4bird)), "id")))
   trajectory[[i]]<-birdtrajectory
   print(i)
 }
```

Now, I have a problem, because `trajectory` is of the class 'list'. I cannot figure out how to unlist it.

Comment: Use do.call with rbind

Comment: You might consider using trip, you need tr <- trip(spdf4tri, c("timestamp", "id"))  and then as(tr, "SpatialLinesDataFrame") will give an multinestring object for each id. (trip is ponderously strict about the input data, and not so helpful and in need of an upgrade - happy to help if you want)

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use do.call for this. Here is an example.

First, add sp library and create a list with three SpatialLines objects (would work with Lines object as well).

```
library(sp)
sp.lines <- list()
  sp.lines[[1]] <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,2)))),ID="a"))) 
  sp.lines[[2]] <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(1,2,3)+0.5,c(3,2,2)+0.5))),ID="b"))) 
  sp.lines[[3]] <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(1,1.5,1)))),ID="c")))
```

Now, use do.call with rbind to merge the lines into a single SpatialLines object.

```
merged.lines <- do.call(rbind, sp.lines)
  class(merged.lines)
  length(merged.lines)
  plot(merged.lines, col=1:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The clue is building the SpatialLines object later, once you have a list of `Lines` objects. The ID MUST be unique, otherwise all your `Lines` objects will have the same ID, and `SpatialLines` will throw an error.

I prepared this example code to illustrate:

```
 library(sp)
 library(raster) # need a raster to generate fake data
 library(dismo)  # I'm using the "randomPoints" function from dismo

 # first we need a canvas
 # we can start with an arbitrary extent
 ext <- extent(-20,10,-10,0)
 r <- raster(ext) # this is our raster object
 r[] <- 1 # let's fill it up with 1's

 indiv <- LETTERS[1:5] # let's say we have 5 individuals with data
 df <- data.frame()
 # we are generating 10 random points per "individual"
 for (i in 1:5)
      df <- rbind(df,randomPoints(r, 10))
 # you will get a warning about the projection, ignore that.

 # with this we can generate a SpatialPointsDataFrame
 spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
              coords=as.matrix(df), 
              data=data.frame(ind=sort(rep(indiv,10))))

 # now we loop for each individual 
 # and store "Lines" objects in a list
 trajectories <- list()
 for (i in 1:length(indiv))
         trajectories[[i]] <- Lines(list(Line(subset(spdf, ind == indiv[i]))), 
                                    ID=paste(i))
 # pay close attention on how the Lines object must be structured:
 # Lines(list(Line(spdf)), ID="unique string")

 # then we simply transform our trajectories list to SpatialLines
 splo <- SpatialLines(trajectories)
```

You can then visualize the data like this:

```
 image(r)
 plot(splo, add=T, col=rainbow(5))
 plot(spdf, add=T, pch=16, col=rainbow(5)[ spdf$ind ])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a list because your asked it to be a list. If your question is to have all your trajectories inside an object that is a `SpatialLines`, you should try this:

```
ids=unique(spdf4tri$id)
trajectory <- list()
 for (i in ids){ 
   spdf4bird <- subset(spdf4tri, id == i)
   trajectory[[i]] <- Lines(list(Line(spdf4bird)), "id")
   print(i)
 }
trajectory.sp <- SpatialLines(trajectory)
```

You have then one `Lines` for each animal. You can also add a dataframe if you have more information on the animals, for instance, with their `id` again:

```
trajectory.sp.data <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(trajectory.sp, 
    data = data.frame(id = ids))
```

Then you can plot with colour depending on `id`:

```
plot(trajectory.sp.data, col = rainbow(length(ids))[trajectory.sp.data$id])
```

I cannot test the script without your data, but this should work.
Is this what you were looking for ?

Comment: The id must be unique. Otherwise, `SpatialLines` will complain about it. So change that part to: Lines(list(Line(spdf4bird)), ID=paste(i))

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative: the `rgeos` package has a function `gLineMerge` to directly merge multiple lines from a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` to a single line:

```
library("rgeos")
merged_lines <- gLineMerge(your_spatial_data_frame)
```